# What cables for electric bass+preamp+pc?

Tags: preamp, cable+, pc, record

I wan't to record a bassline using my PC.
I have a passive electric bass, a behringer mic100 preamp, and a PC with soundcard emu 0404 PCI.

What audio cables do i need for Bass->Preamp and Preamp->PC?
Maybe a usual unbalanced 1/4" jack and a balanced XLR to 1/4" balanced jack? 
I should mention that my soundcard does not have a stereo input but 2 mono inputs for L and R channel. 
Also in soundcard specs says: E-MU 0404 has unbalanced connections.

Comment: Don't you have a mic input on your pc somewhere? Just use a 1/8 to 1/4 or get a 1/4 adapter for your aux cord.

Answer (score 1):

The mic100 only has balanced in/outs. If there is some specific reason you want to use this piece of gear then I would suggest you get a DI-Box. It takes a 1/4" unbalanced and gives you a balanced XLR output. The pre-amp is not needed in a functional sense for what you're doing so keep in mind, unless you're trying to get the "sound" of that piece of gear it's not required.

It's not required that you use a DI-Box but just plugging your guitar into something expecting a balanced input will kill about 3db (half the volume) and be a little noisier. Of course the manual for the mic1000 says you can just plug in a guitar to the input. Yet another reason Behringer is not a respected name in the pro community, unless it's their cable tester that works well.

Now the E-MU 0404 has mic/line inputs. The manual isn't clear and I don't see buttons to switch between mic/line on them so I would assume it's 1/4" for balanced "line" input and the XLR for the 'mic' input which uses a preamp. The mic input is not something you want since it'll be coming in way too hot for that at line level.

So for what you asked here's the cabling I'd use to connect your setup.

> |bass|<--unbalanced 1/4"-----unbalanced 1/4"-->|DI-Box|
>
> |DI-Box|<--XLR-----XLR-->|mic100|<--XLR-----balanced 1/4"-->|EMU0404|

It's possible to use XLR - balanced 1/4" between the DI-Box and mic100 too because the inputs are wired in parallel. Same with the output you could also just use a balanced 1/4" to balanced 1/4" makes no difference. And of course as I said you could also just plug your guitar straight into the mic100 with a 1/4" too it just wouldn't be "right."

Answer (score 0):

```
Guitar -> Unbalanced 1/4" -> mic100
```

And the 0404 has 1/4"/XLR Combo Input, so

```
mic100 -> Unbalanced 1/4" -> 0404(Left or Right Mono)---PC
```

Its okay to use standard connections on the 0404.